# Rename file by date - batch

Tags: date, batch-file, rename

I have a file that is named: xxx_blabla_1
All I need is for it to become xxx_date_1, via a batch command, but it has to be in some unusual date format: Jan0113, where Jan is month, 01 is the day and 13 is the year.
Months are always first 3 letters.

So end result should be: xxx_Jan0113_1

Comment: and where the date is taken from?

Comment: what do you get when you type `echo %date%`?

Comment: npocmaka, it's the date of today.

Comment: with this script you can get date parts of today and use them with `ren` command - http://www.robvanderwoude.com/datetiment.php#DatePart

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to rename, but here is what you would do to get the date:

```
  %date:~3,2% + %date:~0,2% + %date:~8,2%
```

this would return: 010113

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Define month names array (with 2-digits subscripts)
set m=100
for %%a in (Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec) do (
   set /A m+=1
   set month[!m:~-2!]=%%a
)

rem Get today's date parts
for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=/" %%a in ("%date%") do (
   set dd=%%a
   set mm=%%b
   set yyyy=%%c
)

rem Do the rename
ren xxx_blabla_1 xxx_!month[%mm%]!%dd%%yyyy:~-2%
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 @echo off
 setlocal
 set filename=xxx_blabla_1
 for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=/" %%a in ('echo 30/04/2013') do (
    set day=%%a
    set year=%%c
  )
 for /f "tokens=1,3 delims=_" %%a in ("%filename%") do (
    set first=%%a
    set third=%%b
  )
 for /f "tokens=2 delims=/" %%i in (
    'echo 30/04/2013') do set/a mnth=1%%i-100
 set year=%year:~2,2%
 for /f "tokens=%mnth%" %%i in (
  "DEC JAN FEB MAR APR MAY JUN JUL AUG SEP OCT NOV") do (
   echo ren %filename% %first%_%%i%day%%year%_%third%)
```

You can replace the 'echo 30/04/13' with just 'echo %date%'. I had to hard code it since my date format is different than yours. If you get the desired results printed to the screen, remove the echo before the ren to actually do the action.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
:: date format (given) is dd/mm/yy

SET "newbla=01Jan02Feb03Mar04Apr05May06Jun07Jul08Aug09Sep10Oct11Nov12Dec"
CALL SET newbla=%%newbla:*%date:~3,2%=%%

SET oldname=xxx_blabla_1.whatever
CALL SET newbla=%%oldname:blabla=%newbla:~0,3%%date:~0,2%%date:~6,2%%%
ECHO REN "%oldname%" "%newbla%"
```

This assumes that 'blabla' occurs only once in a name.

Now, if you're looking for a more general-case solution, where `_` is used as a delimiter:

```
@ECHO off
SETLOCAL
SET oldname1=xxx_blabla_1.whatever
SET oldname2=yyy_albalb_9.whatever

:: date format (given) is dd/mm/yy

SET "newbla=01Jan02Feb03Mar04Apr05May06Jun07Jul08Aug09Sep10Oct11Nov12Dec"
CALL SET newbla=%%newbla:*%date:~3,2%=%%
SET newbla=%newbla:~0,3%%date:~0,2%%date:~6,2%

FOR /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%m IN ('set oldname') DO (
 FOR /f "tokens=1,2*delims=_" %%a IN ("%%n") DO (
  SET oldname=%%a_%%b_%%c
  CALL SET newname=%%oldname:%%b=%newbla%%%
  SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
  ECHO REN "!oldname!" "!newname!"
  endlocal
 )
)
GOTO :eof
```

Where the `for/f ... %%m...` is simulating say a `dir /b...` listing.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all.

I found some tool that I used for it and that's it. 
Forgot to update it in this post :)